# How to set priority for Agent in ResourcePool or Seize

Tags: anylogic

I have a Seize that used a ResourcePool. What I try to do is to have "priority" depending on an agent variable. I have read that it is possible to do it in both (Seize or ResourcePool), but in https://help.anylogic.com/, there is nothing about it...

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In the seize block you can define your priorities in the priorities section as follows:
[image: priority seize]

In the resource pool you can't define the priority of a task. The only priorities you can define are the tasks related to the resource itself such as breaks, maintenance, etc. But not the priority associated to the agent.